# Execute a mongodb script from c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Say I have a file that contains some mongodb operation (like add a field)
EX.

```
   db.foo.updateMany(
   {},
   { $set: {"new_field": "test"} })
```

How can i run this file using c#?
FYI These commands to need to be read from a file as I plan to have a number of these and track which files ran